# Ajax call returns Object(object), how to get the value from it

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp, spring-mvc

JSP file

```
<div class="container">  
  <table id="headerTable" class="table table-bordered">
   <thead>
     <tr>
      <th colspan="2">Header</th>
     </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <c:forEach items="${headerList}" var="field">
        <tr>
            <th>${field}</th>
            <td><input id="${field}" type="text" class="form-control "></td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>    
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Javascript

```
$('#parseBtn').click(function() {
  var parseMsg = $('#msgText').val();
  alert("parse message is " + parseMsg);
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/parseMessage",
    data: {
      "msg": parseMsg
    },
    success: function(data) {
      //data format looks like Object {SubsystemChannel: "F", MessageNumber: "200257", DebugQueue: " ", WorkStationNumber: "023", FrontEndNumber: "0000"…}

      $('#headerTable input').each(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var field = data.id;
        $(this).val(field);
      });
    }
  });
});
```

What I am going to do is,  go through the $('#headerTable input'), set the value(from data) in it. So, I get the each input id first, then get the value from data using id, but it failed.... Could you help me on this?  thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [Bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) instead of dot notation to access properties using `id` variable

```
$('#headerTable input').each(function () {
    var field = data[$(this).attr('id')];
    $(this).val(field);
});
```

Comment: you save my ass!!  And thank you for providing me the Bracket Notation info!!  my code works now.